# Pluralise a string but also add an extra variable

Tags: javascript, i18next

I might be getting the wrong end of the stick, but I am trying to pluralise a value with [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/plurals) package but also add in a static variable name:

Here is the json:

```json
{
  "likes": {
    "pluralise_zero": "~~{{name}}~~ **liked** your post",
    "pluralise_one": "~~{{name}}~~ and {{count}} other **liked** your post",
    "pluralise_other": "~~{{name}}~~ and {{count}} others **liked** your post"
  }
}
```

And I am calling it like so:

```
t('likes.pluralise', name, count)
```

The like count should be pluralised, but the `{{name}}` should not be. What I'm finding is that when I run this code, {{name}} is also pluralised like which looks something like:

```
{
  count: 4
  name0: "persons name"
  name1: "another name"
  name2: "someone else"
}
```

Is there a way to achieve what I need?

Comment: Did you mean `t('likes.pluralise', {name, count})`?

Comment: "*which looks something like*" - where exactly are you seeing that object? Is it the return value of the `t(…)` call?